# How do i make callbacks on functions activated by ng-click in angular?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting my email code to finish after the function processing it's data is finished. It's trigger by NG-click on a button but none of the usual callback methods are working.

Angular sends post requests to my express server to be mailed.

```
function processQuote() {
  $http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : '/send' ,
    data    : mailJson,
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
  }).success(function(data){
    console.log('success!');
  }).error(function(err,data){
    console.log(err);
  }); 
};
```

loops through mixed object/array table and returns mailJson array I will pump into email

```
$scope.calculateAll = function(callback){
  var mailJson = [];
  var amount = 0;
  $scope.contact.totalQuote = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) {
    if( $scope.customers[i].area != 0) {
      $scope.customers[i].total = parseInt($scope.customers[i].area, 10) * parseInt($scope.customers[i].price, 10);
      $scope.contact.totalQuote += parseInt($scope.customers[i].total);
      mailJson.push($scope.customers[i]);
    }
  }
  mailJson.unshift($scope.contact);
  callback(mailJson);
};
```

and the html, ng-click to activate.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="calculateAll(processform)" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Why would the ng-click need a callback?

Comment: You don't use `processQuote()`? It looks like that's the only async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was little confusing but I got that you want to run block code after response

$http return a deferred promise so what you can do is

```
function processQuote() {
var promise=$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : '/send' ,
  data    : mailJson,
     headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
});
return promise;
};
```

In your controller

```
processQuote().then(function(){
//code should run after a response
});
```